# Reference a variable index in an array keypath?

Tags: ractivejs

Suppose the data of my Ractive contains both an array, and an integer representing the "current" index of my array. Is it possible to use a single keypath to refer to the "current" VALUE in my array? I've tried

```
myRactive.get("array[index]")
```

but this just returns undefined. Does this functionality exist? Or is there a "cleaner" way that I should be doing this?

Edit: I know that I can access each variable individually. What I'm looking for is something more concise, where I could access my data with a single call to get().

Answer (score 1):

You access array elements in the Ractive data as follows:

```
myRactive.get("array")[index]
```

If `index` is in the Ractive data, you can access the array element like this:

```
myRactive.get("array")[myRactive.get("index")]
```

Comment: Sure, I know that. I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing it (putting everything in a single keypath, instead of having to use two separate calls to get()).